# How to access to the EntityManager from the UserProvider class

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I would like to acces to the **EntityManager** from a **UserProviderClass** for be able to instantly persist users in my database after they log-in via an API.

But this class implements **UserProviderInterface** and do not extend **Controller** so this code can't work:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

Here is the full class

```
<?php
namespace am\ContributionBundle\Objects;

use am\ContributionBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username){

            // Processing to the authentification using curl

            $url = 'exemple.com/api.php?pseudo='.$username;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
            curl_close($ch);

            try {

                $user = // ... looking for user in DB
                // How to ??

                if (null === $user) {
                    // ... user creation
                }

                return $user;

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username));
            }
    }

    function supportsClass($class){}

    function refreshUser(UserInterface $user){
       return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }
}
```

How can I get an instance of the EntityManager here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware. Then you can use the container to find any object.

Also remember to configure it as a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Thx, I solve the problem extending Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager and adding **arguments** to se service config